# MySQL NOT EXISTS: Exclude rows where value does not exist for a field (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql

I'm working with the Wordpress databases *wp_users* and *wp_usermeta*. I want to list users from *wp_users* who do not have the term "birdie_log" in the column "meta_key" in *wp_usermeta*.

wp_users

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Abe |
| 3 | Jane |
| 4 | Mark |

wp_usermeta

| ID | meta_key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | wpuf_user_status |
| 2 | birdie_log |
| 2 | wpuf_user_status |
| 3 | birdie_log |
| 3 | wpuf_user_status |
| 4 | wpuf_user_status |

I tried to accomplish this by joining the tables and using MySQL NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT wp_usermeta.meta_key 
    FROM wp_usermeta 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'birdie_log'
```

I expected to see a list of users who do not have 'birdie_log' in the meta_key field, but no users are listed at all. In the example above, I would ideally see John and Mark listed because their meta_key column does not contain the 'birdie_log' value anywhere for them in the *wp_usermeta* table.

Comment: You have mentioned `wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID`;
Is there another column in `wp_usermeta` with `user_id` ?

OR

You accidently referred `user_id` as `id` while providing table data

Answer (score 0):

The following query using `NOT EXISTS` shall return you list of users who do not have 'birdie_log' in the meta_key field as in the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5cdf82/2).

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM wp_usermeta 
  WHERE wp_usermeta.ID = wp_users.ID 
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'birdie_log'
);
```

Output :

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 4 | Mark |

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN`. You just need to correlate the `EXISTS` subquery with the main query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM wp_usermeta 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'birdie_log'
    AND wp_user_meta.user_id = wp_users.id
)
```